# A limit with infinite product $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^4}\prod_{i=1}^{2n}\left(n^2+i^2\right)^{\frac1n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, integration, limits

How to calculate : 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}\prod_{i=1}^{2n}\left(n^2+i^2\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Comment: Take logarithm of both sides maybe. This transforms product into sum and powers into products.

Comment: Hint: Rewrite the logarithm of this as a Riemann sum...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pull the $n$ out of the product to get

$$L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{i=1}^{2 n} \left ( 1+\frac{i^2}{n^2} \right )^\frac{1}{n} $$

Rewrite as (corrected!)

$$\log{L} =  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{2 n} 
 \log \left ( 1+\frac{i^2}{n^2} \right )$$

This is a Riemann sum whose limit is

$$\begin{align}\log{L} &= \int_0^2 dx \: \log{(1+x^2)}\\ &= [x \log{(1+x^2)}]_0^2 - 2 \int_0^2 dx \: \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \\ &= 2 \log{5} + 2 \arctan{2} - 4 \end{align}$$

Then the limit $L$ is

$$L = 25 e^{-2 (2-\arctan{2})} $$